How to configure split-brain protection and recovery for IAtomicLong?
Hazelcast IMDG 4.2.7.
Documentation states that it can be done with such a config:
<atomic-long name="default">
    <merge-policy>PutIfAbsentMergePolicy</merge-policy>
</atomic-long>

But Hazelcast refuses to start on this config with following exception:

Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.config.InvalidConfigurationException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config":atomic-long}'.

As you can see config class really does not contain a field for AtomicLong configuration. Looks like documentation is stale and references to IMDG 3.*  version.
So, how to configure split-brain protection and recovery for IAtomicLong? XML and programmatic configuration will be useful both.

Looks like CP subsystem should be configured to tolerate nodes crashes, since AtomicLong has become a part of it
